# Sitecore How to check if an Item has a certain field

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore7.2

For the sitecore item `testItem` how can I make sure that this item has the field "`Title`".

I am asking because I am creating some fields in an item's template programmatically. So a field should not be created again if it already exists.

Because with this code I can get if the field has some value or not.

```
testItem["Title"] 
testItem.Fields["Title"]
```

Comment: Just check for null. It's simply a collection.

Comment: What if the Field `Title` exists but it contains null?

Comment: Then it won't be null but it's `.Value` will be

Comment: Do you want to consider inherited fields as belonging to the current template? For example if current template does not have "Title", but the parent template does, what would you like to happen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please check this code, you are checking if item, fields collection and field value is not null

```
if(testItem!= null && testItem.Fields != null && testItem.Fields["Value"] != null)
{
  string name = testItem.Fields["Title"].Value;
}
```

Comment: .. or with some C#6 null propagation magic :)

`var value = item?.Fields["Title"]?.Value;`

Answer (score 2):

Code below will return value, including Standard or Default value for the field:

```
        if (testItem.Fields["Title"] != null && testItem.Fields["Title"].HasValue)
        {
            string title = testItem["Title"].Value;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To save having to check the field against your *testItem* more than once you could cast to a field and then: check the field for null, that it has a value and then retrieve the value.

The advantage here is that if you need to access the field in several places you don't have to retrieve from *testItem* each time.

e.g.

```
Field titleField = testItem.Fields["Title"];

if (titleField != null && titleField.HasValue)
{
    //do something with value
    string fieldValue1 = titleField.Value;

    //or (see intellisense for params)
    string fieldValue2 = titleField.GetValue(true);
}
```